# About Google Colab and other cloud services for big data projects

Tags: azure, google-colaboratory, amazon-sagemaker

I don't have GPUs and looking for options to run big data projects with neural networks. I came to know about Google Colab pro which supports mounting google drive. Now that raises the following questions:

1. **Does google colab pro support mounting local directories**?
   -- to answer this question, I didn't find any article or tutorial that addresses this issue. In most cases, a small chunk of data was uploaded to google drive and then the drive was mounted.
2. In that case, google drive has only 15GB of storage space. And the data I am working with is significantly large. -- to address this issue Google one has a storage space plan like 200GB/year costs 30$ which is pretty cheap. **Are there options to increase storage otherwise**?
3. That brings the question: **is additional 200GB storage(if I go for that) accessible to google colab**? Are there such restrictions from google?
4. **What are the other best options apart from Google colab**? I have AWS account and know just abcs about amazon sagemaker, and no idea about Azure cloud.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I have purchased a Google Colab Pro subscription for running Samtools with Big Data (90 Gb BAM files stored in my Gdrive) saving new files directly to my Google Drive in a few minutes (thanks to GPU Runtime)

1. I cannot mount my PC HDDs yet but I can easely upload whichever file from my computer and better than that: I can copy links from my usegalaxy.org account and import to Google Colab with a single code url-to-my-file i.e.
   !wget https://usegalaxy.org/api/datasets/f9cad7b01a472135213e1eea624b4d04/display?to_ext=bam
   more info here https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb
2. I purchased a year ago a Google One account with 2 Tbs by $100. In fact, I could mount all my Drive Files before I purchased Google Colab Pro and running files until 80 Gbs space. You don't need to pay for running single files. However, GPU Runtime is very helpful for Big Data processing, I can slice 100 Gb BAMs in a few minutes, faster than usegalaxy servers

Answer (score 0):

1. I do not think this is supported
2. Looks like this is the only option
3. It should be, yes
4. Have you looked at SageMaker Studio Lab (https://aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/studio-lab/)? It was just launched a couple of months ago (so in preview and might take a few days to get approved for an account), but is free (similar to colab) and some some really cool additional features (more space, github integration, etc.).